# How to get to the different paradox endings?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I am aware there are 7 different paradox endings and that you must use time-reversal in specific gates.

I was just wondering if there was a comprehensive list of the different endings. I have only encountered two and don't want to try every single possible combination to get them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [eight paradox endings are found here.](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Paradox_Endings)

**Paradox Ending #1: Eternal Repose**
Tell Lightning ‘I accept this world’ in a live trigger conversation during Episode 5 – Neo Bodhum.

Rest of the endings are all Spoiler. You should witness these only if you have finished the main-story and are collecting 160 fragments. ***Remaining Paradox Endings require you to be equipped with Grand Cross Fragment Skill, unless otherwise stated.***

**Paradox Ending #2: Departing Together**
Go to City of Academia AF4XX and use Time Reversal. Talk to Hope and Alisa until they ask parts of Graviton Core. Give them to Alisa and then in the live trigger conversation, refuse the Artifact.

**Paradox Ending #3: War of the Giants**
Go to Bresha Ruins AF005 and use Time Reversal. Defeat Atlas without weakening him first.

**Paradox Ending #4: Defeating a Flan with a Flan**
Go to Sunleth Waterscape AF300 and use Time Reversal. Defeat Flan King with Snow as an ally. Once story cut-scenes have ended and you can explore freely, approach Flan King a second time and defeat him to unlock this paradox ending.

**Paradox Ending #5: Atonement’s Dreams**
Go to Oerba Village AF200 and use Time Reversal. Find and defeat Caius in the northwest rooftop to unlock this ending.

**Paradox Ending #6: Soul Replica**
Go to Augustia Tower AF200 and use Time Reversal. Find and defeat Demi-Fal’Cie Adam at the top of the tower to unlock this ending.

**Paradox Ending #7: End of the World’s Sky**
Go to City of Academia AF4XX and use Time Reversal. Talk to home and Alisa until they ask part of Graviton Core. Give them to Alisa, then in live trigger conversation, accept the Artifact. Exit back to the city and enter gate to the Time-Space Interval with Artifact you just received from Alisa.

Follow along the path and talk to Yule as you did in the main story, then defeat Caius in 1-on-1 battle with Serah. It’s a very challenging fight even on easy difficulty with level 99 in all 6 roles and a Tier 5 monster companion.

**Paradox Ending #8: Successor to the Chaos**
You don’t need Grand Cross for this paradox ending. Go to City of Academia AF4XX and use Time Reversal. Go to City of Academia AF4XX and use Time Reversal. Talk to home and Alisa until they request part of Graviton Core. Give them to Alisa and then in live trigger conversation, accept the Artifact.

Exit back to the city and enter gate to the Time-Space Interval with Artifact you just received from Alisa. Follow along the path and talk to Yule as you did in the main story, then defeat Caius in 1-on-1 battle with Serah (Grand Cross = Off).

Follow along with the events in Neo Bodhum. Turn Grand Cross On here and in a live trigger conversation with Lightning, tell her ‘I won’t accept it’. Enter the time distortion to A Dying World AF700. Follow along the events as you did in the main-story, then defeat Caius in a 1-on-1 battle with Noel (Grand Cross ON).

**Final Fantasy 13-2 – Secret Ending**
Once you have collected all 160 fragments, go to City of Academia AF500 (Grand Cross ON). Defeat Caius and 3x Chaos Bahamuts as you did in the main story. After the same ending events, there will be a bonus cut-scene at the end of those cut-scenes, that is the secret ending.

Anomalous achievement/trophy will pop-up after watching the Secret Ending.

Comment: First part is unnecessary and a massive spoiler for people that haven't completed the game

Comment: @user1016253 My apologies - edited